# DataGridview Inside custom user control

Tags: c#, datagrid, user-controls

In my winforms application, I have a custom user control in which I am adding another custom user control which consist of a data gridview and a text box and a binding source.

I am trying to load the data grid view with the binding source which is loaded by  a list supplied at the time of the instantiation, unfortunately the data grid view is not loaded with any data. Surprisingly the number of rows in the the data grid view is 550.   why my data grid view  shows no data despite the fact that the binding source as well as the data grid view have number of rows 550.?

in the first user control the code is as follows

```
 private void buttonBase1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ucItemList uc = new ucItemList(listAirports, "AAC", this);
        this.Controls.Add(uc);

    }
```

In the Second User control,

```
public ucItemList(ListAirport listAirports, string iataText, ucReport1 parent)
    {
        InitializeComponent();            
        ItemToDisplay = listAirports;
        IataText = iataText;        
        SetData(ItemToDisplay, iataText);      
    }
 private void SetData(ListAirport la, string iata)
    {
        itemBindingSource.DataSource = la;

        dgvItemDetails.DataSource = itemBindingSource;           

    }
```

Comment: Does your DGV have any columns? Are they preset at design time? If not, is `AutoGenerateColumns` set to `true`?

Comment: @Ivan Stoev     I haven't  changed it , the default option is AutoGenerateColumns  is true.

Comment: So you see columns but no rows? Or no columns? Probably we need to see the `Airport` and `AirportList` classes.

Comment: I dont see any thing neither the columns or the rows, normally it should show data. But I dont know what happens here

Comment: @Ivan Stoev    As I tested by adding a datagridview into the first user control and loaded the data onto it. It works perdectly.

Comment: Strange. Anyway, w/o some sort of a repro there is nothing we can do.